# Transformer Coils

Tags: transformer, current-transformer

If a transformer's primary or secondary coil is just un-insulated copper wire, why dosent the current take the path of least resistance, why does it want to go around the whole coil? Please help, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Because the wire is ***not*** uninsulated! Look up "magnet wire" or "enameled wire." It will look something like this:

[image: magnet wire]

It's coated with a flexible coating that allows you to wind a transformer without an overly thick and obstructive insulation (more windings in smaller spaces, that way.)

Otherwise, you'd probably be right and the current would just take the shorter route possible.

Comment: Oh ok. So I've been playing with transformers and I hooked it up to 120v Ac and it started to smoke. On the secondary winding I measured the resistance from input to center tap and it's like 1,000 ohms which it wasn't before but from input to output it's only 3-5 ohms.

Comment: @RanzSayaman If you've smoked a transformer, it's probably bad. If the wire gets really hot, it can melt or burn through the thin insulation. It's possible that the wires also made contact with the transformer core, too. And that can be yet another path. Be careful and make sure you know which side of the transformer is designed for 120VAC, too. It's important.

Comment: @RanzSayaman By the way, it is a great deal of fun and empowerment to learn how transformers and coils work and to wind your own designs. However, it does take some learning and studying to get some of the important concepts. But once you do, it opens up a whole other world to you that you didn't have access to before. So it's worth some effort, if you someday feel up to the idea.

Comment: You might add, 'why can we use such thin insulation?' Because of the pecularity of where it's used, it's only rated to about 50v, and only has the minimum feasible handling/abrasion resistance.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yeah. I might have. But when I'm winding these things, its the difficulty of putting enough turns into the window I've got available that matters at the moment. (I almost never think about the handling and abrasion aspects because the materials are good enough that it doesn't cause me much trouble.) I also care a lot about core volume and Webers. But that's not about the wire.

Comment: I once had a project tripped up for months because an engineer went off the rails chasing the white rabbit that 'ohms law did not apply in magnetic circuits', after winding enamelled wire on cores without enough attention to the handling abrasion aspect, and got shorted turns.

Comment: @Neil_UK I guess I must be gentle, then. I've never had a short in anything I've done. But I've only wound in the hundreds, and most of those were toroids, so maybe not yet enough experience. Usually, my problems are that if I find a core with the right cross section area and volume, I seem to want to use wire that's too thick so I can't get all the windings I need onto the toroid. And then there was that crazy idea I had of delivering half a Joule in a single pulse from a triggered 1kV source into a load of a few ohms, matching the load with a toroid transformer.